# Haskell caught directory not exist but not empty value

Tags: haskell, exception, directory

With the `LambdaCase` I am able to filter out if a dir does not exist. However: if a user is prompted and hits enter (empty) I still get an exception. 
I think `Maybe` or `Either` can help me here, but I have a hard time figuring out how to set this up.

```
    {-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}


    import System.Directory 
    import System.IO

    dirExist = do 
      a <- prompt "Directory:> "
      doesDirectoryExist a >>= \case 
        True -> getDirContent a
        _ -> putStrLn "Directory does not exist or invalid value specified." 

getDirContent :: FilePath -> IO () 
getDirContent dir = do  
  result <- getDirectoryContents dir 
  mapM_ putStrLn $ result 


    prompt :: String -> IO String 
    prompt x = do 
      putStr x 
      a <- getLine 
      return a
```

Comment: What is `getDirContent`? I can't find it anywhere. I'm guessing it's a function you wrote yourself; in that case, could you include its implementation in your code sample? (I need it to get a [mcve])

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can replace the line:

```hs
doesDirectoryExist a >>= \case
```

with:

```hs
((&&) <$> (pure $ not $ null a) <*> doesDirectoryExist a) >>= \case
```

This is called "applicative style" (in case you didn't know it ;-)); I am combining two IO operations that return a boolean using the AND (&&) operator.

The (pure $ not $ null a) expression checks that the string isn't empty, and uses "pure" to lift a pure operation into an IO (so we can combine it with doesDirectoryExist into an expression that checks for both conditions).

EDIT:

As Joseph noted, the above executes doesDirectoryExist whether it is needed or not; you usually want to avoid that (unless you somehow rely on its side effects); you can avoid it with bradrn's suggestion; you can also do this:

```hs
(if null a then pure False else doesDirectoryExist a) >>= \case
```

Alternatively, since you dislike if-then-else notation (as do I):

```hs
(case null a of True -> pure False; False -> doesDirectoryExist a) >>= \case
```

Not really cleaner, though; you can import Data.Bool and do this:

```hs
-- import Data.Bool
(bool (doesDirectoryExist a) (pure False) $ null a) >>= \case
```

("bool" is just a more functional-like notation for the good old if-then-else)

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is equivalent to `unless (null a) $ doesDirectoryExist a >>= \case` (using `unless` from `Control.Monad`), which is simpler while doing the same thing. Even as someone who really likes applicatives, I did have trouble parsing your statement.

Comment: typedfern's solution is not exactly the same (I know what applicatives are, but not so experienced to know what to use when). It returns the error-message, while your solution (bradm) terminates the call without a message. Both your solutions learned me a lot. Thanks for that (even without the missing code). Alhough bradm's code is more terse, typedfern provided the info I was looking for.

Comment: `((not (null a) &&) <$> doesDirectoryExist a) >>= \case` is exactly equivalent to what's in this answer, but way less complicated. Also, note that this way has the flaw that the `&&` can't short-circuit the IO bit, whereas bradrn's `unless` way doesn't have that flaw.

Comment: Joseph is right, doing (&&) <$> ioOp1 <*> ioOp2 executes ioOp2 even when unneeded - doesn't harm in this particular case, but best avoided; fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `doesDirectoryExist ""` returns `True`, but whatever is in your `getDirContent` function (which you'll need to post if you want a more detailed answer) doesn't work when passed `""`.

There's no need for `Maybe` or `Either` to fix it. Just wrap the block in an `if` construct, and put something like `putStrLn "You must enter a directory name"` in the `else`.

Comment: Joseph Sible: added getDirContent. I am not to keen on if..then..else. Like `case` and guards more, seems a little clearer, hence the reason I did not choose that construct.

Comment: @Madderote if you understand how to do it with if-then-else, rewriting it to use `case` and guards is trivial.

Comment: you're right. Excuse my comment. It is just that I like to clean looks of case and guards better.